# whatsapp-messenger group members, Why 256?

Tags: database-design, whatsapp

Previously whatsapp had group members limit of 100, which is now increased to 256.
Same is the case with [broadcast list](https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/general/30046788).

Why?

Answer (score 0):

A single byte holds numbers 0 to 255. Any number larger than 255 needs 2 or more bytes. 0 to 255 is actually 256 numbers, which would be why they put this limit.

Comment: How can we explain migration from 100 to 256 with this logic?

Comment: You'd have to ask the developers of whats-app. At a guess, the designer picked 100 as a nice round number (which also fits in a byte). Since they were using a byte, at some later point they thought they might as well use all of it. But only the developers can know for sure.